# Why ./script/generate is needed instead of script/generate in some Rails instruction?

Tags: bash, shell

Inside of Bash or Windows (or any other shell), is it needed to do

```
./script/generate scaffold foo name:string
```

instead of just using

```
script/generate  ...
```

?  I do see the first form sometimes, but the second form always works for me, on Mac OS X or Ubuntu, even if the PATH doesn't include the `.` (current directory)

So can the second form always work, so the first form is really not needed?  I think for executable, we sometimes use `./a.out` to run it... but seems like maybe `script/generate` doesn't need the `./` in front?

Comment: If `.` is not in your $PATH, and the program cannot be found in the $PATH, you have to name the program explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean exactly the same thing.

> Starting from the current directory, select a subdirectory called 'script' and in it an executable called 'generate' and run it.

The difference is that with `./` you're explicitly specifying the current directory and without it, it's implicit.

Comment: I was thinking that `script/generate` may resolve to `/bin/script/generate` if my PATH has `/bin` in it and it contains `script/generate`... but I just `sudo` and created such file and it didn't work... otherwise, it can happen before resolving to the current directory...  but the fact that some advanced people use it, I am thinking maybe there are some rare cases they might be different, for example, in a different shell like csh or zsh

Comment: 動靜能量: When a shell sees a slash, it knows that a directory is being specified so it doesn't use the `$PATH`. The slash is what it looks for to make the decision whether to look in the `$PATH`. This is the same in csh and zsh.

Comment: So you mean -- No matter you have `.` or not in your PATH, when `script/generate` is used, PATH is irrelevant, and both versions work EXACTLY the same?  Is there a shell that behaves differently? -- for common shells anyway, because anybody can write a shell that makes them behave differently.

Comment: 動靜能量: Yes, they work the same regardless of whether `$PATH` includes `.`. I'm not aware of any shell that behaves differently in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 syntaxes of invocations in POSIX shell:

- Running a program by specifying a name and then searching it in `PATH` enviornment variable - this one is used when program's name has no slashes (`/`).
- Running a program by specifying full path to it manually - absolutely (path starting with `/`) or relatively (path starting with any other symbol). This one is chosen when program's name includes at least one `/` - thus it's a path, not just a name of file.

In your case, both ways to invoke - `script/generate` or `./script/generate` are executed using variant #2 - by specifying a path to the program. `./` is an alias to current directory and in some cases it's required to be present (for example, when using `cd` command, you can't just say `cd` without argument and expect to change into current directory - `cd` reserves call without arguments to change to `$HOME` directory - but you may call `cd ./` if you want to cd into current directory), but it's not required in this case of invocation.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at [4 Ways of Executing a Shell Script](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/execute-shell-script/) and [Shell Script Execution Guidlines](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/shell-script-execution-guidelines-for-newbies/). The main difference between both styles is:

```
script/generate  ...
```

won't work if the parent directory of *script* does not lie in your current PATH environment. (Well this sure depends on how the shell's lookup method is implemented. There might be implementations that - to a last resort - are looking within your current working directory).

**EDIT**
Ok, I've done some research on this as I myself didn't seem to be knowing what the difference is. So, this is what I've arrived at:

The `./` (dot slash) syntax is an alias for the **absolute path** of the current working direcotry, so that - with e.g. `/home/peter/script` being the cwd -

```
peter@linux:/home/peter/script$./myscript
```

is expanded to `/home/peter/script/myscript`. The slash dot alias basically gives the shell a hint at where to find the executable/script.

That hint is what's essential, and that's the reason why

```
peter@linux:/home/peter$script/myscript
```

works as well whereas

```
peter@linux:/home/peter/script$myscript
```

won't. The former aids the shell in finding the right executable/script by providing some sort of reference point (namely the `script` directory). The latter, on the other hand, leaves the shell with a possibly ambiguous command, as there could be a homonymous script within the user's $PATH.

So, to come to an end, both of the styles you've asked the difference for do basically the same - giving the shell a hint at where to look for the executable/script. The shell then is able to unambiguously resolve the correct file and will happily execute it.

Have a nice day.

Comment: hm... but the first form is not a "dot space dot slash"... it is merely "dot slash" which is to specify the path...

Comment: Sorry, I've just taken a quick look and mistook the first example. I've edited my answer.

Comment: no, as I said the `.` is not in the PAHT...  actually... maybe the first form is to prevent any other `script/generate` some where in the PATH from running... and that it must be the current directory... but ... supposedly we trust things in the PATH...

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with those answers except that they are too long - it's just about your PATH.  If your path includes '.' then either way would work
That said, it's a bad habit to put '.' in your PATH for security reasons, so stick with './'

Comment: the thing is, even if the PATH doesn't include `.` the two versions seem to work exactly the same on my Bash on Mac OS X.  Dennis Williamson's comment suggests that "No matter you have `.` or not in your PATH, when `script/generate` is used, PATH is irrelevant, and both versions work EXACTLY the same"

Comment: But with the ./ you do not run the risk of running another instance from another dir (if that one is in your path)

Comment: If you specify a directory, then the `PATH` is not used. There's no risk. `./dir/prog` is ***exactly*** the same as `dir/prog` (the exception is if the program does something with `$0` that depends on knowing the directory where the program resides [which it really shouldn't](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)).

Comment: Dennis, I stand corrected.  I must have been confusing this with the include behavior of a C preprocessor (where directories can be used to extend elements of the path).  All that said and dne, there is nothing wrong with specifying ./, or getting in the habit of specifying it (as you wont have the directory safety net when for executable in the current directory.

Comment: The **general** case is `dir/executable` where `dir` can be `.`, `foo`, `bar/baz` or `/all/the/way`.